# How to SFTP without prompting password?

Tags: linux, sftp

I am using ubuntu (release 4.15.0-72-generic).

I have written multiple shell scripts to connect to a destination Linux server using sftp. But sftp is prompting me for a password.

Is there any way to stop the prompt without using sshpass/rsa key configuration?

Answer (score 1):

Generally it's the best practice to have a password for SFTP users.

But still if you have to enable the password less authentication please follow the below steps:

I have followed as:

```
SSH Client : 192.168.0.12 ( RHEL )
SSH Remote Host : 192.168.0.11 ( AML )
```

Step 1: Create Authentication SSH-Keygen Keys on – (192.168.0.12)

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa
```

Step 2: Create .ssh Directory on – 192.168.0.11

```
ssh sheena@192.168.0.11 mkdir -p .ssh
```

Step 3: Upload Generated Public Keys to – 192.168.0.11

```
cat .ssh/id_rsa.pub | ssh user1@192.168.0.11 'cat >> .ssh/authorized_keys'
```

Step 4: Set Permissions on – 192.168.0.11

```
ssh user1@192.168.0.11 "chmod 700 .ssh; chmod 600 .ssh/authorized_keys"
```

Step 5: Login from 192.168.0.12 to 192.168.0.11 Server without Password

```
ssh user1@192.168.0.11
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: @Mahui if this works please accept the answer: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: He specifically asked to not use ssh-keys.